# Bootstrap Modal - Deleting a Review using Django

Tags: html, django, modal-dialog

I'm using a simple Boostrap modal and it works fine. I have a delete URL which will delete the review based on the id. My issue is, I don't know how to pass the review.id from the button, through to the modal confirm delete button.

If I don't use a modal and just do a simple delete button, it works fine using:

How do I pass that review.id through to the final button?

```
{% url 'delete_review' review.id %}
```

HTML:

```
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated and user.username == review.name or user.is_superuser %}
        <div>
            <a class="btn btn-black rounded-0 text-uppercase mt-2" href="{% url 'edit_review' review.id %}" role="button">Edit</a> |
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <a class="btn-delete btn rounded-0 text-uppercase btn-outline-danger mt-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" role="button">Delete</a>
            
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <hr>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete Review</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            Are you sure you want to <strong class="text-danger">DELETE</strong> your Review?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete_review' review.id %}">Delete Review</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What about using `<a>` tag like you did for Edit ? Put it just on top of the button. You’ll have something like: `<a href="{% url 'delete_review' review.id %}"> <button …>Delete Review</button> </a>`

Comment: Omg. I can't believe it was that easy. Sometimes I do wonder.... I really thought some complicated ID passthrough had to occur here. That the delete button in the modal was unaware of the review.id or something. Maybe I shouldn't study coding lol! Thanks!